# Second bar open value under scenario condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, indicator

I ask you for a hand to get out of this problem: as you can see from the code below, I'm trying to create a 5-thick red line at the opening price of the second daily candle (I'm viewing the chart with a 30-minute timeframe) so I want to get the opening value as soon as the 10:00-10:30 candle is closed and consolidated. I tried to extrapolate the opening of the second candle as you can see, but it gives me back the opening of the second candle of the previous day. how can I do? do you have ideas?

Thanks so much to anyone who can help me

```
 //@version=5
indicator('Custom Gap Indicator', max_lines_count = 500, max_boxes_count = 500, shorttitle='CGI', overlay=true)

// Parameters
gap_threshold_percent = input(0.1, title='Gap Threshold (%)')
spread_percent = input(5, title='Open Stoploss Gap (%)')
multiplier = input(1.5, title='Take Profit Multiplier')
WRB_MIN_VALUE = input(75, title='WRB min value to range min-max (%)')
DOJI_DEF = input(30, title='Doji max value to range min-max (%)')
DOJI_in_trend= input(1, title = "Doji in trend? (1=yes  0=no)")
DOJI_in_trend_max_val= input(6.0,title = "Max val Doji in trend body (%)")
Min_value_SL=input(1.0,"Min Value Stop Loss gap ($)")
    
// gap value
gap = open - close[1]
    
// gap is bearish or bullish 
is_bearish_gap = gap < 0
        
var firstBar = 0
var secondBar = 0
var secondOpen = 0.0
var line openLine = na
    
newDay = ta.change(time('D'))
firstBar := newDay ? bar_index : firstBar
secondBar := bar_index == firstBar + 1 ? time : secondBar
secondOpen := bar_index == firstBar + 1 ? open : secondOpen

    
// Scenario 1: bullish gap (DOJI/CANDELA PICCOLA inversione a rialzo)

if math.abs(gap) > close[1] * gap_threshold_percent / 100 and is_bearish_gap and open <= close and (close - open) / (high - low) <= DOJI_DEF / 100 and (high+((high-open)* spread_percent / 100)-open)>= Min_value_SL
    opening_price = open
    highest_or_lowest = high
    line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=open, x2=bar_index + 12, y2=open, width=2, color=color.orange) 
    box.new(left = bar_index,top = highest_or_lowest + ((highest_or_lowest-open) * spread_percent / 100) , right = bar_index+12, bottom = open - (multiplier * ((highest_or_lowest-open) +((highest_or_lowest-open) * spread_percent / 100))),text="DOJI/PICCOLA SHORT" ,text_color=color.red, border_color=color.red,border_width= 0,bgcolor = color.rgb(215, 43, 43, 86))
    line.new(bar_index+1, secondOpen,bar_index+11 ,secondOpen,color = color.red,width = 15)

//Scenario 2 etc................
```

look at the picture to better understand the problem and help me solve it

[look the wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDny9.png)